# problem with imputing in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, data-cleaning

I have used SimpleImputer() to fill the missing values

```
my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
data_with_imputed_values = my_imputer.fit_transform(train_data)
```

what I expect is that my dataframe is filled with the mean of that column for the missing cells.
yet it only works for one column and doesnt work for the other one.

To explain better the problem, here is the number of missing values before imputation

[image]

then here is the result after imputation
[image]

why does it only work for column-Embarked but not for age?

Answer (score 2):

In the second cell you are printing the `isnull()` on `train_data`... But you have applied imputer on `train_data` and assigned values to `data_with_imputed_values`... Try replacing `train_data` in the second cell with `data_with_imputed_values`.

```
missing_val_count_by_column = (data_with_imputed_values.isnull().sum())
missing_val_count_by_column
```